# Should /var/log/wtmp be always present in a new Ubuntu 14.04 installation?

Tags: 14.04

I am setting up ubuntu 14.04 and just installed `chkrootkit`, which gives a warning:

```
"unable to open wtmp-file wtmp". The file /var/log/wtmp is missing.
```

From googling, it's unclear to me if this file is always present in Ubuntu 14.04 from the start.

The man page says:

> wtmp is maintained by login(1),  init(8),  and  some  versions  of getty(8)  (e.g.,  mingetty(8)  or  agetty(8)).   *None of these programs creates the file,* so if it is removed, record-keeping is turned off."

<sup>(my emphasis)</sup>

Elsewhere, at http://blog.mattbrock.co.uk/hardening-the-security-on-ubuntu-server-14-04/, there is a hardening step `touch /var/log/wtmp`, which suggests the file needs to be manually created.

Can anyone advise how & when `/var/log/wtmp` is created?

Comment: I think it should be present. It not being present on a cloud image led to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1019338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/log/wtmp` is created during the installation of the package `base-files`.

The post-installation script (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst`) contains the following code:

```
if [ ! -f /var/log/wtmp ]; then
    echo -n>/var/log/wtmp
  fi
...
chown root:utmp /var/log/wtmp /var/log/btmp /var/log/lastlog
```